# Set the Read-only property of a File

Tags: java, readonly

I am trying to set the read-only property of a File, but it doesn't seem to work. Could someone please help me to understand why.

Here is my code...

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("c:/ulala.txt");
        if (!f.setReadOnly()) {
            System.out.println("Grrr! Can't set file read-only.");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it "not work", are there any error messages, exceptions or does it just print "Grr! Can't set file to read-only." ? Your code works for me.  Does the file exist? If not, the setting read-only won't work.  Can you manually set the file to read-only?  If not it may be a permissions problem.

Comment: Yes, the file (ulala.txt) is exist.

Comment: but, when i open the windows explorer, and i want to check the result in windows explorer, the file still enable to copy.

Comment: when you say "the file is enable to copy", do you mean that you can still copy the file to another location?  Read-only only prevents overwriting the file, not copying it (i.e. reading the contents and writing a copy of the somewhere else).

Comment: ooooh... you mean, read-only can't make the file not copied?? so , how to make the file can not copied with permission way? waow, thank you before

Comment: You can't.  If you can read it, you can make a copy of it.  The only way to prevent someone copying it, is to take their read permission away.  Just think of a normal text file, you could open the file in notepad, make a copy of the content and create a new file, voila, your file is copied.  The only way to prevent that is to prevent reading.

Answer (score 0):

The file must exist *and* the user must have permission to change the permissions for the file. You can test if the file exists using `f.exists()`.